# Dirac measures on the real line

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p \in R$. 
Define a measure on the set of subsets of $R$ as follows: 
$\delta_p(E) = 1$ if $p \in E$ and $\delta_p(E) = 0$ otherwise for some $p \in R$. 
Question: Suppose we have a measure $m$ defined on the subsets of the real line that takes only the values $0$  and $1$. 
Prove that $m$ is either $0$ everywhere or it is equal to the $\delta_p$ for some $p$.

My approach : 
Suppose we have $m$ that takes only the values $0$ and $1$. 
By countable additivity $m$ cannot take $1$ on any two disjoint sets. 
So there is only one set call it $X$ on which $m$ can be $1$. 
Now we have to find a $p$ in this $X$ to make it the same as $m$ but I don't see how?

Comment: I think your realization about additivity is pretty much what you need. You've narrowed the statement down to saying that $m$ cannot be $1$ at more than one point and so it is either identitcally $0$ everywhere or $1$ at one point (and therefore $0$ everywhere else). These are already the $0$ measure and Dirac measure. You don't need to construct $p$.

Comment: So I can just take any point $p$ in the set $X$ and use it for the dirac measure? I think so too but it's just a bit counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: The _point_ (http://instantrimshot.com/) is that you don't need to _pick_ any point. The property of the Dirac measure is that it's $0$ at every point except one point and it is $1$ at that point, regardless of what the point is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not completely trivial: after all, it is conceivable that $m$ is $0$ at every point without being the zero measure.

Assuming $m\neq 0$, one has to show that $m(\{ p\})=1\;$ for some point $p\in\mathbb R$.

First, note that it is not possible that every $x\in\mathbb R$ has an open neighbourhood $V_x$ such that $m(V_x)=0$. Indeed, since $\mathbb R$ has a countable basis of open sets, it would follow that $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} V_n$, where $(V_n)$ is a sequence of open sets such that $m(V_n)=0$ for all $n$; and hence $m=0$ by countable sub-additivity.

So there is some point $p\in \mathbb R$ such that $m(V)>0\;$ for every neighbourhood of $p$; so $m(V)=1\;$ for any such neighbourhood. Taking $V_n=(p-\frac1n, p+\frac1n)$, so that $\bigcap_n\downarrow V_n=\{ p\}$, it follows that $m(\{ p\}) =\lim(V_n)=1$.

Note that the required conclusion does not hold true if you only assume that $m$ is *finitely* additive: take any nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\mathbb R$, and consider the finitely additive measure $m$ defined by $m(A)=1$ if $A\in\mathcal U$ and $m(A)=0$ if $A\not\in\mathcal U$.

Comment: Aha, now this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!